# Determinant of rational links

Tags: knot-theory, knot-invariants

On page 9 of his book "An Introduction to Knot Theory", Lickorish just mentions the fact that the determinant of the rational knot $K(p,q)$ is $|p|$.

I'm trying to find a proof of this fact (I looked into other books and papers but did not find this again). It says "see Chapter 9" but I did not really see where in chapter 9 he proves this fact (also I must say that I did not look into Goeritz Matrix yet).

Is there another way to prove this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rational tangles (and their closures, rational knots/links) can be nicely understood through double branched covers, which is related to something called the Montesinos trick.

For the following, the illustrations come from the [Sketches of Topology](https://sketchesoftopology.wordpress.com/2008/01/25/double-branched-covers-of-rational-tangles-and-the-montesinos-trick/) blog.

Recall that a *$2$-tangle* is a $1$-manifold $T$ properly embedded in a $3$-ball $B$ such that $\partial T$ is four points in $\partial B$, and equivalence of tangles is isotopy rel $\partial B$.  One characterization of a *rational* tangle is one that is two trivial ball-arc pairs (in the terminology of Lickorish) glued along a disk in their respective boundaries.  That is, there exists a properly embedded disk $D\subset B-T$ such that $B-D$ is a disjoint union of trivial ball-arc pairs.  In the following ball, $D$ is the blue disk, and the two yellow disks demonstrate triviality of the ball-arc pairs.

[image: Rational tangle]

The double branched cover of a rational tangle $(B,T)$ has a nice characterization as being a solid torus $S^1\times D^2$ with the branch locus $T'$ being trivial:

[image: Double branched cover]

The disk $D$ lifts to two copies in the solid torus, and the yellow disks lift to four disks that fuse into being two meridian disks.

A rational knot/link (a.k.a. a two-bridge knot/link) is a knot that is formed from a pair of rational tangles glued along their boundaries.  We may assume one of these tangles is trivial, and then this is called a closure of a rational tangle.  The double branched cover is from taking two copies of the solid torus and gluing them together.  That is, it is a lens space.  I'm not exactly sure about conventions for $K(p,q)$, but to match what you state from Lickorish, the knot $K(p,q)$ must have as its double branched cover $L(p,q)$, which is from doing $p/q$ Dehn surgery on an unknot in $S^3$.

If $X_2$ is a double branched cover, $\lvert H_1(X_2)\rvert$ is the determinant of the knot (see Chapter 9 of Lickorish).  Since $H_1(L(p,q))=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$, then $\lvert K(p,q)\rvert = \lvert p\rvert$.

Comment: Thanks! I still need to look at it a little bit more in details, but then it should be correct if $p$ and $q$ in $K(p,q)$ are coprime integers.

Comment: @user2795243 Yeah, $p$ and $q$ ought to be coprime for a rational knot (and also for lens spaces).